Export fbx file with hidden objects but importing with all objects unhidden
I want to export a model with hidden objects as a fbx file, but when I import this file, all those hidden objects become unhidden. I wonder if it is possible to remain the hidden states after importing?
The first picture shows the state before exporting, the second one is the export settings, and the last one shows the state after importing.




https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

@DuarteFarrajotaRamos Thanks!
